# How to do 'beforeEach' only at Fixture level and not for each test under that fixture

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I want to run 'beforeEach' only at the fixture level and not for each test under that fixture

```
fixture `Fixture A for Use Case1`
   .beforeEach(login)

test('A Test 1', async t => {
      await t 
      ---
    }); 

test('A Test 2', async t => {
      await t 
      ---
    });
```

```
fixture `Fixture B for Use Case2`
    .beforeEach(login)

test('B Test 1', async t => {
      await t 
      ---
    }); 

test('B Test 2', async t => {
      await t 
      ---
    }); 
   
test('B Test 3', async t => {
      await t 
      ---
    });
```

## What Is Happening

The login function is being run before every test under 'Fixture A' and 'Fixture B'

## What I Need

I want 'login' to run once at the start of every 'Fixture' and not for every test under the fixtures.

Is it possible? I couldn't find a way on documentation.

Answer (score 4):

This is achievable via User Roles and the 'preserve url' option.  TestCafe's documentation explains it here:  https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html#optionspreserveurl