# TestCafe BeforeEach / Before

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

Am trying to use the before() at TestCafe Fixture level.

My Goal is : Create Before() at fixture level, and this contains login Page scripts.  So my plan is to run before() method before all other tests. I have 3 groups of code

```
1) Before() -- login code. 
2) test1() -- sample code-1
3) test2() -- sample code-2
```

My requirement is: once the login is succeeded then test1(), test2() should use the same login which is defined in before().  Can you please help me here,
note: i tried using Testcafe-Live but did not succeed.

my test scenarios are: Before the test login method should be executed one time before executing test1 and test2. Also, the browser window should not close after each test

Answer (score 3):

Similar question:  [How to do 'beforeEach' only at Fixture level and not for each test under that fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624400/how-to-do-beforeeach-only-at-fixture-level-and-not-for-each-test-under-that-fi)

You could achieve this by using .beforeEach() on the Fixture and then using 'preserve url' option on the UserRole: TestCafe's documentation explains it here: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html#optionspreserveurl